# How to access second subnet that has IP cameras but don't want them to have access to the internet

Tags: subnet

My setup is:

Internet modem/router with IP range of 192.168.0.X

Debian PC's and Android tablets are connected to that via Ethernet cabling or Wifi.

NVR with 16 cameras. The NVR has an IP address of 192.168.0.60 and it's possible to connect from the outside into the NVR via RTSP. I haven't activated the external access yet. The IP cameras are all set up with the IP range 192.168.1.x (not 0.x)

What I would like:

I would like my PC's and tablet to be able to rtsp into the IP cams using the IP cameras subnet 192.168.1.x to maintain them directly and to view the streams via my tablet or PC. Maybe even use a program like Motion to view the IP cams from a different room to where the NVR is located.

How can I set up one PC for instance? My PC has access to the internet via 192.168.0.2 > Router 192.169.0.1 but I want to RTSP using VLC streaming accessing the subnet of the NVR 192.168.1.XXX where XXX represents an individual camera, one of 16 cameras.

Kind regards and thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to give you a helpful answer since you've provided very little information about your setup.  If you want to create another subnet (192.168.1.0), you probably will need a different router, or perhaps a layer 3 switch.  You need to be able to route between the subnets.

Comment: I thought I was being quite clear. I already have two subnets as explained. I want to keep the camera subnet 192.168.1.X off the internet but accessible to my PC's and a tablet.

Comment: You've said nothing about how your devices are interconnected. Do you have a router and/or switch?  If so, what kind?

Comment: I understand now. I have a router 198.168.0.1 and the NVR 192.168.0.60 is connected to that. The cameras are all on 192.168.1.XX which are plugged directly into the NVR. The second subnet is what the NVR has set.